# How to change certain div color base on number

Tags: reactjs

```rb
import React from 'react';

class Chart extends React. Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      divs:[]

    };
  }

  displayForm() { 
    for(let i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
       this.state.divs.push (<div key={i} className ="item">{i}</div>)
    }
    return this.state.divs;
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className ="container">{this.displayForm()} </div> 
    ); 
  }
}
export default Chart
```

Right now, I have created 10x10 div. But, I have no idea how to change the color for a certain amount of items.  like if I pass 10 to the 10x10 div. there will be 10 items is green. If I pass 0 to the 10x10 div. there will be all same color.

Comment: You need to write application logic to handle that. This has nothing to do with React, but JavaScript

Comment: That's not the best way to set the state, you can check de pen I made, I explain a little bit in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check for that number in your loop

```js
import React from 'react';

class Chart extends React. Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      divs:[]

    };
  }

  displayForm() { 
    const num = this.props.num;
    for(let i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
       // Here we choose the color
       const color = num < i ? 'green' : 'red';
       this.state.divs.push(
         <div key={i} className ="item" style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>{i}</div>
       )
    }
    return this.state.divs;
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className ="container">{this.displayForm()} </div> 
    ); 
  }
}
export default Chart
```

EDIT: There are better ways to write this component, I just add one of them to clean some code [here](https://codepen.io/joseluismurillorios/pen/gOYrQqj?editors=0010).

Comment: Before edited , the code is bad since directly modify state is bad desigh.Right?

Comment: Is better to avoid mutations on your data flow

Comment: but it's kind of weird if the props are select options. Then, every time, when the prop.num change, it will create one more div.

Comment: You can discard the previous ones creating a new array, then setting the state to that new array of divs

Comment: can you show it to me on codepen if you have time. Sorry, I am new in react

Comment: No problem, just want to know how do you need to pass the number prop, i will make one with a single input

Comment: Like there are select options which contain 3 numbers. When users select 1 it will be the props that pass to chart. Therefore, the chart will base on the this.props.number and then render the chart. it will be 99's green, and 1 red. Your case in code pen is like what I said. But I just don't want every time when I change the number, it create one more div.

Comment: I updated the codepen, I made it as simple as possible, I just didn't have time to add comments, any doubts you can tell me

Comment: that what I want, thank you so much for waste your time.

Comment: It is not a waste of time if it was possible to help you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to pass a number to `displayForm()` function to make it be a `displayForm(number)` function to change the *number* of items of a certain color? Since you have 100 divs, do you want first ten to be of that color or last ten? Anyway, you can do this logic yourself but the only line I would modify in your `displayForm()` function is this one:

```
displayForm(number) { 
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let newDiv = i < number ? <div key={i} className ="item color">{i}</div>
                            : <div key={i} className ="item">{i}</div>
    this.state.divs.push(newDiv);
    }
  }
  return this.state.divs;
}
```

Where the `color` is the class assigning a color to your div. You can change the logic inside the if statement.